# How to write text for copy to clipboard directive in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have made a copy to clipboard directive which contains the following code

```
    import {
    Directive,
    Input,
    Output,
    EventEmitter,
    HostListener
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[copyClipboard]'
})
export class CopyClipboardDirective {
    @Input('copyClipboard')
    public payload: string = '';

    @Output('copied')
    public copied: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    public onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!this.payload) return;

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.payload.toString());
        this.copied.emit(this.payload);
    }
}
```

And the test file for it has the following UTs

```
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { configureTestSuite } from 'ng-bullet';

import { CopyClipboardDirective } from './copy-to-clipboard.directive';


describe('Copy to Clipboard directive', () => {
    let component: Dummy;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Dummy>;
    let directiveInstance, directiveEl, element;
    let homeServiceSpy;
    const originalClipboard = { ...global.navigator.clipboard };
    configureTestSuite(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [
                Dummy,
                CopyClipboardDirective
            ],
            providers: [],
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        writeSpy = jasmine.createSpy()
        originalClipboard.writeText = writeSpy;

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Dummy);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(
            By.directive(CopyClipboardDirective)
        );
        element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div'));
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create an instance', () => {
        expect(directiveEl).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('default event should be prevented', () => {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('click', {
            key: '',
            cancelable: true
        });

        element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('copies the right text', () => {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('click', {
            key: '',
            cancelable: true
        });

        directiveEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
     
        expect(originalClipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy text');
      
    });

    it('does not copy', () => {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('click', {
            key: '',
            cancelable: true
        });

        element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        directiveEl.payload = 'hello';
        expect(originalClipboard.writeText).not.toHaveBeenCalledTimes();
    });
 
});

@Component({
    template: `<div copyClipboard="copy text">

    </div>`
})
class Dummy {}
```

In the copy test cases there are a lot of errors

```
<toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got Object({ writeText: <getter> }).
```

What is proper way of writing these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer -
Spy should be create like below

```
writeSpy = jasmine
                .createSpy('writeSpy')
                .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('copy text'));
    
            global.navigator.clipboard.writeText = writeSpy;
```

Test case would be like this

```
it('copies the right text', () => {
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('click', {
            key: '',
            cancelable: true
        });

        element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```